# How to show all the metadata about images?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, exif

I am trying to read the metadata of my images using Pillow's `TAGS` functionality. I use the following code to get this information:

```
# imports
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
    
imagename = 'image.jpg'
image = Image.open(imagename)

exifdata = image.getexif()
for tag_id in exifdata:
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id,tag_id)
    print(tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # we decode bytes
    if isinstance(data,bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f'{tag:25}: {data}')
```

The result I get is similar to the following output:

```
ImageWidth               : 4128
ImageLength              : 1908
ResolutionUnit           : 2
ExifOffset               : 226
Make                     : samsung
Model                    : SM-M205F
Software                 : M205FDDS8CUC1
Orientation              : 8
DateTime                 : 2021:06:18 12:08:37
YCbCrPositioning         : 1
XResolution              : 72.0
YResolution              : 72.0
```

The problem is that critical data, that I need, is not in the list. For example focal length, metering mode, exposure time, and other metrics and details are not there, though I can see them by right clicking my image in the "Properties" section as the following image shows:

[image: metadata from properties]

Why Pillow's `TAGS` can't read all the details. Is there any way to make it get all the details needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties that you've mentioned - focal length, metering mode and exposure time - are within the EXIF IFD - https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html

Since Pillow 8.2.0, `getexif()` only returns the top level tags. To get the data within the EXIF IFD, you need to use `get_ifd()`.

To take some code from the other answer here and modify it,

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def print_exif_data(exif_data):
    for tag_id in exif_data:
        tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        content = exif_data.get(tag_id)
        print(f'{tag:25}: {content}')

with Image.open("Tests/images/flower.jpg") as im:
    exif = im.getexif()
    
    print_exif_data(exif)
    print()
    print_exif_data(exif.get_ifd(0x8769))
```

I get

```
ResolutionUnit           : 2
ExifOffset               : 196
Make                     : Canon
Model                    : Canon PowerShot S40
Orientation              : 1
DateTime                 : 2003:12:14 12:01:44
YCbCrPositioning         : 1
XResolution              : 180.0
YResolution              : 180.0

ExifVersion              : b'0220'
ComponentsConfiguration  : b'\x01\x02\x03\x00'
CompressedBitsPerPixel   : 5.0
DateTimeOriginal         : 2003:12:14 12:01:44
DateTimeDigitized        : 2003:12:14 12:01:44
ShutterSpeedValue        : 8.96875
ApertureValue            : 4.65625
ExposureBiasValue        : 0.0
MaxApertureValue         : 2.970855712890625
MeteringMode             : 2
Flash                    : 24
FocalLength              : 21.3125
UserComment              : b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
ColorSpace               : 1
ExifImageWidth           : 2272
FocalPlaneXResolution    : 8114.285714285715
ExifImageHeight          : 1704
FocalPlaneYResolution    : 8114.285714285715
FocalPlaneResolutionUnit : 2
SensingMethod            : 2
FileSource               : b'\x03'
ExposureTime             : 0.002
ExifInteroperabilityOffset: 1416
FNumber                  : 4.9
CustomRendered           : 0
ExposureMode             : 0
FlashPixVersion          : b'0100'
WhiteBalance             : 0
DigitalZoomRatio         : 1.0
MakerNote                : b'\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00(\x00\x00\x00D\x04\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x94\x04\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9c\x04\x00\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xda\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xe6\x04\x00\x00\x06\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\xee\x04\x00\x00\x07\x00\x02\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x05\x00\x00\x08\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00;\xe1\x11\x00\t\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00&\x05\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x01\r\x00\x03\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00F\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x030\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xaa\x02\xe3\x00 \x00\x95\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff1\x00\xe0\x08\xe0\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xaa\x02\x1e\x01\xd7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x14\x01\x95\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x020\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x03\x00\x00\x95\x00!\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00IMG:PowerShot S40 JPEG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Firmware Version 1.10\x00\x00\x00Andreas Huggel\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x03\x00\x01\x80z\x01\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\xc6\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
SceneCaptureType         : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "official" [`Image.getexif`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getexif) method, you can use the older, not really documented [`Image._getexif`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=_getexif) method (attention, that's a protected member of the `Image` class):

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


def print_exif_data(exif_data):
    for tag_id in exif_data:
        tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        content = exif_data.get(tag_id)
        if isinstance(content, bytes):
            content = content.decode()
        print(f'{tag:25}: {content}')
    print()


# https://github.com/ianare/exif-samples/blob/master/jpg/mobile/jolla.jpg
imagename = 'jolla.jpg'
image = Image.open(imagename)

print_exif_data(image.getexif())
# ExifOffset               : 146
# Make                     : Jolla
# Model                    : Jolla
# Orientation              : 1
# DateTime                 : 2014:09:21 16:00:56
# XResolution              : 72.0
# YResolution              : 72.0

print_exif_data(image._getexif())
# Model                    : Jolla
# Orientation              : 1
# DateTime                 : 2014:09:21 16:00:56
# ExifOffset               : 146
# XResolution              : 72.0
# YResolution              : 72.0
# Make                     : Jolla
# ExifVersion              : 0230
# ShutterSpeedValue        : 4.643856189774724
# ApertureValue            : 2.526068811667588
# DateTimeOriginal         : 2014:09:21 16:00:56
# ExposureBiasValue        : 0.0
# FlashPixVersion          : 0100
# WhiteBalance             : 1
# ISOSpeedRatings          : 320
# MeteringMode             : 1
# Flash                    : 0
# FocalLength              : 4.0
#                     34864: 3
#                     34867: 320
# ExposureTime             : 0.04
# FNumber                  : 2.4
```

At least for the linked test image, focal length, exposure time, etc. are properly extracted.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the older' ?

Comment: `getexif` (public function) and `_getexif` (private, experimental function as per the documentation) are different methods. (Somewhere in the documentation, the latter is also referenced as "the older".) If you dig through the Pillow source code, you find lines, such that it seems that `_getexif` is the same as `getexif()._get_merged_dict()`. But, although calling the public function `getexif`, you still access a private function, `_get_merged_dict()` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna read/modify an image's EXIF,
another alternative/recommended module
is pyexiv2 (https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2)

```
>>> import pyexiv2
>>> img = pyexiv2.Image(r'.\pyexiv2\tests\1.jpg')
>>> data = img.read_exif()
>>> print(data)
>>> img.close()
```

click the url above, read tutorial for more information.