# Python - extracting EXIF metadata from image using PIL. Failing to replicate results produced at exifdata.com

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I am using:

- Python   3.8.5
- Pillow   8.2
- ExifRead 2.3.2

I am trying to extract the EXIF data from [this image (as a random example)](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/friends-celebrating-together-royalty-free-image/1271333791).

Here is what I have tried so far:

#### using ExifRead:

```
import exifread

with open('/path/to/image/file', 'rb') as f:
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)


print(tags) # No EXIF data found
```

#### Using PIL

```
from PIL import Image

img = PIL.Image.open('/path/to/image/file')
exif_data = img.getexif()
```

Again, this produces paltry results

However, when I upload the same photo to an [oline exif data checking service](https://www.exifdata.com), I get the full EXIF data.

How can I fix my code so that I can extract the same data that is available to exifdata.com?

Comment: import PIL.Image
img = PIL.Image.open('img.jpg')
exif_data = img._getexif()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I read the exif data for an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image)

Comment: @pippo1980: The suggested links do not help - in fact, the code I am testing came directly from those links. The Image interface has changed, and the `_getexif()` method has been replaced by `getexif()`.

Comment: tried to ask here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/discussions ?

Comment: oes https://exiftool.org/ works?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli `_getexif` probably still provides more information than `getexif`, cf. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68033479/11089932). Do you have access to the real image you linked - or do you use preview? In the first case, how should people here be able to reproduce any results? Likely no one will pay any money to get that image. On the other hand, if you use the preview, what results do you exactly get when feeding to the linked service - for comparison?

Comment: Your question asks for extracting EXIF, not XMP or IPTC. I think you already get what you ask for.